# Invalid object name 'Users' when reading from Users table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm building a registration page and one of the things I need to do is to check if the supplied email already exists. Here's my code for that:

```
// Check if email already exists in the database
cn.Open();
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email", cn);
Command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _Email;

SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
Reader.Read();
if (Reader.HasRows)
{
    // Email already exists
    Reader.Close();
    Feedback.Text = "That email is already in use, please use another";
}
else
{
    // Doesn't exist, proceed
}
```

When this code is run, I get the following exception which is fired on the `COmmand.ExecuteReader()` line:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Users'.`

From what I know, it means it can't find the Users table. It's definitely there, I just created it and I can see it under the Server Explorer window:

[image: Screenshot]

Also, within my connection string I have `Initial Catalog=db_74;` so it's using the correct database.

So, I'm at a loss as to what could be going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly permissions, which use is the connection connecting as?

Comment: It's connected as the same user that I created the table on. The user does have the permissions, as I can insert data directly into the table from Server Explorer. :/

Comment: Nothing stikes me as obviously wrong, what happens if you try select from an information_schema view?

Comment: Worked it out, apparently I can't be connected to the database under Server Explorer and try to run the code at the same time, maybe it only allowed one connection per user or something. A pain that I have to disconnect every time I want to debug the page but at least it works.

Comment: can you show your connection string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663238/writing-to-an-sql-database-with-asp-classic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using SqlExpress your Connection String Should must be this :

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db_74.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```